# Disable Sonar Build Stability plugin in Preview Mode

Tags: sonarqube

I'm new to sonar and installed this Build-stability plugin. But when i run it locally i get this error.

> Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Access to the secured
>   property 'sonar.build-stability.username.secured' is not possible in
>   preview mode. The SonarQube plugin which requires this property must
>   be deactivated in preview mode.

How to disable a plugin in different modes? Any other help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the Settings > General page and the add the "buildstability" plugin part of the default list of plugins to be excluded for Preview and Incremental modes. Ticket created to make this behavior the default one : https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4980.

Comment: This answer should be accepted. Worked for me. Thanks!